# Android:Socket programming between phone and system

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I am trying to write a client server application, in which the client is a android device.

I am not confident on socket programming.

I have written a server side application and a client side that runs on my emulator.

Will the same application work between a real android device?

Comment: I'm not networking expert. But as long as your server app has a static IP, it should also work from outside your pc. (i.e. running it on a phone) When I read your post, you have not tested it using a phone + pc. Do you not have an android device at your disposal? It is the only way to test

Comment: Thank you...

and ya my server has a constant IP and i hope it works...

yes i am not having an android device..which has caused the problem....i am trying to manage 1...

Comment: To be honest, I don't think anyone can answer you're question in this case. You need to either share your application, or test it yourself and come back if you have problems. We can help you with problems, not with predictions.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your question (once its reviewed it will show up). From what I understand, your question is generic. It works on my emulator, will it work on my device.

The answer is yes. The emulator connects to 10.0.2.2 which redirects to 127.0.0.1 on your host machine right ? This is how you would have got it working.

To get it working from a device you will need to do the following

1. Load your java server on your real ip address on your desktop
2. Ensure that your desktop is on the internet and the ip address visible to the internet (open)
3. Ensure that your android phone points to the public ip address of your desktop.

Now, I know your worry :) open ip address. So, you can use a ec2 (free amazon ubuntu instance), install java on it and run your server as java -jar . From eclipse you can export a jar file (runnable jar file) with lib in your jarfilename_lib path.

Comment: i did not use 10.0.0.2 ...rather the public IP of my system directly..and it works there.... 
do u mean by this 
"Ensure that your desktop is on the internet and the ip address visible to the internet (open)" 

my laptop must be connected to internet??

thanx..

Comment: It's either, your desktop connected to internet and have an exposed IP, or use a LAN like connection from your pc to tablet. For example sometihng like tethering.. But I assume that you want to be able to make the connection from within the bar which is 5 km away from your desktop but with free wifi(just an example). In this case, yes your desktop needs to have an internet connection to be reachable.

Comment: @RC-user when I said 10.0.0.2, I meant with your emulator test. And its not 10.0.0.2, its 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Yes, your laptop/desktop what ever you are deciding to use as server.

Comment: thanx a lot....

both 10.0.2.2 as well as the static IP work.... i m using the static IP for emulator test as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) For android via HTTP request. 
[Here](http://krams915.blogspot.de/2011/02/spring-3-rest-web-service-provider-and.html) is an example.
When you have static ip in server you should set that static ip in your actual device.If you are running your app on emulator you must set 10.0.0.2.